# How to differentiate type-c and lightning charger programmatically on iOS & iPad

Tags: ios, ipados

How to differentiate type-c and lightning charger programmatically on iOS & iPad?

A simple solution is to hard code a mapper from device Model to charger type, but you need to maintain it with new device iteration. Is there any new APIs available to know its charger type. Thanks in advance.